# "No Endpoint Listening" in WCF Service Hosted in Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, service-reference

I have WCF service hosted by Windows service.

This is my app.config file (server-side)

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="Service.WebexClient"  behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.0.101:8413/MyWebexService"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>

        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpGetUrl="http://192.168.0.101:8413/MyWebexService/Help"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

so I am on another PC on the Network trying to add service reference and I got the Arror above:

An error (Details) occured while attempting to find services as 'http://192.168.0.101:8413/MyWebexService/help'

Details:

There was an error downloading 'http://192.168.0.101:8413/MyWebexService/help'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.0.101:8413
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://192.168.0.101:8413/MyWebexService/help'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.0.101:8413/MyWebexService/help that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
Unable to connect to the remote server
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.0.101:8413
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

The Service is start and I manage to get to it from the hosted PC

Comment: Please share the details with us. We'd like to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can reach the service from the hosted PC, but not from a different PC, then there is likely a problem with a firewall or Internet proxy.

Can you ping the IP address of the service from the remote PC?

Comment: I van ping from the hosted to the client but I cannt ping from the client to the Hosted